# Faça um programa que leia um número inteiro N e depois imprima os N primeiros números naturais ímpares

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    int n,imp;
    
    printf("Digite um número:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n!=0){//para Zero n ser considerado par
        if(n%2!=0){
            while(imp<n){
                imp=n+2;
                
                printf("%d",imp);
            }
                
                
                
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Quando executo ele apresenta somente o próximo número impar e para. Mas, o que deve acontecer é, caso o usuário digite 9, deve aparecer os próximos 9 números impares - 11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27. Caso digite 3 apareça (5,7,9) e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

> *ele apresenta somente o próximo número impar e para*

O problema está aqui:

```
while(imp<n){
    imp=n+2;
```

Na verdade, o problema começa um pouco antes, porque você não atribuiu nenhum valor a `imp` antes de usá-la, então [o valor desta variável será indeterminado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457) e pode ser que nem entre neste `while`. Se "funcionou" no seu caso, é por coincidência, mas [você não pode programar por coincidência](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/201972).

Enfim, mesmo que entre no `while`, logo na primeira iteração você faz com que o valor de `imp` seja igual a `n + 2`. Ou seja, agora `imp` terá um valor maior que `n` e portanto a condição `imp < n` não é mais satisfeita. Por isso que o `while` só executa uma vez.

---

Para o programa funcionar, você tem que considerar os requisitos dele:

- o valor lido (`n`) é a quantidade de números, então ele deverá ser usado como controle do *loop*
- o `n` também determina qual é o valor inicial a ser impresso: é o número ímpar imediatamente depois de `n`

  - ou seja, se `n` for ímpar, o valor inicial é `n + 2`
  - se `n` for par, o valor inicial é `n + 1`

Daria para fazer algo como:

```
// obtém o valor inicial a ser impresso
int num;
if (n % 2 == 0) // se n é par, o valor inicial é n + 1
    num = n + 1;
else // se n é ímpar, o valor inicial é n + 2
    num = n + 2;
```

Ou podemos usar o próprio resultado de `n % 2` (o resto da divisão por 2, ou seja, é zero para números pares e 1 para ímpares):

```
int num = n + 1 + (n % 2);
```

A partir daí, sabemos que `num` é um número ímpar, então para obter os próximos ímpares, basta somar 2 a ele. Faço isso `n` vezes. Ficaria assim:

```
int n;
printf("Digite um numero: \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
// se n é ímpar, soma 2 para encontrar o próximo ímpar, se for par, soma 1
int num = n + 1 + (n % 2); // n % 2 é o resto da divisão por 2, então se for ímpar será 1, se for par será zero

// assim, num é o primeiro número ímpar imediatamente depois de n
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // repito o for n vezes
    printf("%d\n", num);
    num += 2; // como num é ímpar, posso somar 2 para ir para o próximo ímpar
}
```

Dá para fazer ainda mais curto, aproveitando o fato de que em um `for` podemos inicializar e incrementar múltiplas variáveis:

```
int n;
printf("Digite um numero: \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
for (int i = 0, num = n + 1 + (n % 2); i < n; i++, num += 2) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    int n,aux=0,vezes;
    
    printf("Digite um número:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    vezes=n;
    if(n!=0){//para Zero n ser considerado par
        if(n%2!=0){
            while(aux<vezes){
                n+=2;
                printf("%d-",n);
                aux++;
            }
                
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou d+!